# Hello, how can I trigger the button click on enter please? ReactJs

Tags: reactjs

how can I trigger this button click on enter please, because whenever I click enter it just reload the page.

```
        <input
          value={summoner}
          onChange={(e) => setSummoner(e.target.value)}
          placeholder="Summoner"
        />
        <label>EUW1</label>
        <button
          type="button"
          onClick={() => history.push(`/summoner/${summoner}`)}
        >
          <strong>SEARCH</strong>
        </button>
```

[Code Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tgvTq.png)

Comment: Please post text rather than links to pictures of text.

Comment: Please post text instead of picture

Comment: okay, I edited the post!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution would be to add an `onSubmit` to the form tag and on that function call the  event preventDefault to avoid redirecting and then remove the onClick method from button and change its type to `submit` something like this:

```
const handleSubmit = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  history.push(`/summoner/${summoner}`);
};

...

<form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
    <input
      value={summoner}
      onChange={(e) => setSummoner(e.target.value)}
      placeholder='Summoner'
    />
    <label>EUW1</label>
    <button type='submit'>
      <strong>SEARCH</strong>
    </button>
  </form>
```